# Get-ChildItem using PoshRSJob

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, get-childitem

I can't quite get my head around how to use the module PoshRSJob and would appreciate some help.  It basically should output all the files older than $TargetDate.  Sounds simple right....

```
if (-not (Get-Module PoshRSJob | Measure-Object).count){Import-Module PoshRsJob -Verbose}

$ArchiveDirs = Get-ChildItem $DataPath -Directory

$ArchiveDirs.FullName | Start-RSJob -Name {$_.Name} -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err  | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $TargetDate} | Select FullName, Length, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_.FullName
        Size = $_.Length
        LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
        LastAccessTime = $_.LastAccessTime
    }
}

Get-RSJob | Wait-RSJob -ShowProgress | Receive-RSJob
```

I was expecting to get an object containing all the files older that $Targetdate; which is around 320, instead I get random output 5 times.

- Name           :
- Size           : 55
- LastWriteTime  :
- LastAccessTime :

If I do a Get-RSJob, I see that they all completed with errors.

Comment: You don't explain what your actual issue its. Guessing games waste time. Are you not getting any output I imagine from this?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's late where I am.  I've updated it with a bit more information, hopefully that makes it a little less like a game.

Comment: Those variables likely are null as they are not in the script block scope. I don't know about start-RSjob but you need to add arguments to it in short. If you tried to echo `$targetdate` is it null?

Comment: yep that looks to be an issue. I put the time directly in the scriptblock and sadly that get's me to another issue where it throws an error saying cannot convert value of type "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" to type "System.DateTime"